# how to set an aspect on a constructor

Tags: java, aop

I now that I can set a aspect on a constructor like:

```
pointcut teller(): call (new(..));
```

but that is on any constructor, wat do I have to do when I want only on the class Klas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
pointcut teller(): call (Klas.new(..));
```

I don't have a dev environment for aspectj here but what I remember that was the way to create a pointcut for a specific constructor.

I think you could even do

```
pointcut teller(): call (my.testpackage.*.new(..));
```

and it should include all constructor calls within the package, but my memory could be incorrect.